# xtext imports not working

Tags: intellij-idea, import, xtext

I'm just getting started with xtext 2.9.2 on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3. I try to follow the simple [15 Minutes Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html#run-generated-plugin%20xx). The first iteration was fine, but the imports do not work.

I have created 2 repos on github:

- [the project which defines the DSL](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial)
- and [the project that uses the generated editor](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial.project)

  - when I define everything in a [singleFile](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial.project/blob/master/src/singleFile.dmodel) it is okay
  - but when I split the model into 3 files (same like in the example), then the imports are not recognized: my DSL editor reports an error

    - e.g. [commons.dmodel](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial.project/blob/master/src/commons.dmodel#L3) will complain: `couldn't resolve reference to type String`
    - The String data-type is defined here: [datatypes.dmodel](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial.project/blob/master/src/datatypes.dmodel)

How does xtext try to resolve the imports? e.g. does it automatically look for all my *.dmodel files in the whole project?

Comment: does your project have yourdsl facet? i dont see it on github. and i am not sure that that old xtext version works with that new idea

Comment: Hey, I've downvoted you because SO prefers code to be placed in the question itself, not linked on other sites (even github) because the links go stale and the question will become worthless to future generations. If you can provide a [mcve] I'll remove it.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich: what is the newest version of xtext? the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html) only shows 2.9.0. Or do you mean, that I should use an older IntelliJ version (V15)?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I doubt that there is some problem with the code anyway, because this is straight out of their tutorial. Thus, in order to reproduce it (if possible at all), you need all 2 projects (and maybe even the correct IntelliJ version installed). Posting all files of the those projects here on SO and maybe attaching the complete IDE is for sure not an option..

Comment: First you should add the facet

Comment: @ChristianDietrich do maybe know if this can also work in Android Studio (v2.2.3)? I cannot find a way to add a facet.

Comment: I found out that [Android Studio and IntelliJ use the same project format](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/). So I just opened the Android Studio project in IntelliJ, added the facet, saved the project and reopened in Android Studio: that worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [project that uses the generated editor](https://github.com/tmtron/xtext.15minTutorial.project), I had to go to `File` - `Project Structure...` - `Modules` and add the `Domainmodel` facet:

[image]